# Is it all sites in public beta that have Pro-tem moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators, beta-phase

I noticed [Tor](http://tor.stackexchange.com) is now in public beta, then i went to check their [moderators](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) to see those who were chosen as Pro-tem moderators.

I was suprised to meet it with no names. Is it all sites that go into public beta that will have Pro-tem moderators?

Comment: For the initial period the stack exchange team act as moderators, then Pro tem moderators are chosen

Comment: @RichardTingle I thought stack exchange team act as moderators in private beta then elect pro-tem in public beta

Comment: Read [Robert's blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) on this.  It explains the entire process since your are interested.  In there it mentions that the pro-tem mods are appointed about a week into *public* beta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this answer regarding the process of launching a new site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199551/what-is-the-stack-exchange-staff-process-of-launching-a-site) pro-tem moderators are chosen early in the life of the public beta

> Public Beta
>
> Appointing Pro Tem Moderators — A few weeks after launch, we start the
>   search for “pro tem moderators” who will watch over the site prior to
>   the general elections (when the site graduates). This process may take
>   awhile depending on how clearly candidates emerge from the early
>   community, and how amenable they are to taking on that role. We try to
>   appoint three candidates in the first round, but we may start with
>   fewer and appoint the rest as soon as we can if the process drags on
>   too long.

As such there will be a short time in public beta during which the stack exchange team are still acting as moderators