# Are there any light-hearted lists of SE site milestones?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history

I am curious if there is a list of milestones for a Stack Exchange site which includes both more formal milestones like entering and leaving Area51 commitment phase, private and public beta, and first "trusted user" and more light-hearted milestones like first homework question (and first such question closed as too localized), first spam post, and first site-specific meme?

Given how long Stack Exchange has been mature and the creativity and playfulness of many of its users, I am inclined to believe that at least one such list exists. However, my very limited Googling did not find anything appropriate.

Comment: Is this what you're thinking of? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200383/238110

Comment: Well, all sites that went through Area 51 are still available there through search, e.g. [gaming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming). Stack Overflow however never went through that process so as far as I can tell, no such data exists.

Comment: @Ana No, that only includes (some) of the formal milestones and none of the more playful ones like "first homework question".

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton that's an easy one... "Day 0... even on gaming.se"

Comment: @MichaelT I *think* Writers.SE took surprisingly long to get a homework question, but I could be mistaken.