# Any help hosting a closed site?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, data-dump, closed-sites

With the site "On Startups" [recently closed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/site-on-startups-is-closed-what-to-do-now/), I understand that its content now is only available via [Data Dump](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business). It is however much less user-friendly. I wonder if SE can provide any help hosting it in a form similar to the actual site? I am sure many former users will find it very helpful.

Comment: @Moo-Juice ...he was referring to the data dump

Comment: I don't quite get it - if they closed it, it's because they don't want to host it in a form it was, right? So what are you asking for?

Comment: @Mołot But they allow anyone else to do it. Then why not help with what they can do better and faster? It doesn't have to be the same site, just more user-friendly than downloading the data, that's all.

Comment: But why? If they found that hosting it costs them more than it earns, why would they continue? "they can do better and faster" is reason for you to want it, not for them to do it. On the other hand, hosting one compressed file is virtually free, no one downloads it anyway (not in amounts that would matter).

Comment: @Mołot It is a question whether they can help, not why. Simple yes or no.

Comment: I was going to download the data dump and relaunch it again, improving it beyond what SE could. Would you like to work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150091/162102) from Community Manager Robert Cartaino, Stack Exchange is not going to host archives of closed beta sites.  He addresses these reasons:

- It doesn't make the internet better (it will never be improved)
- It hurts the network (Googlers will evaluate SE as a whole based on closed, stale sites)
- It impedes future efforts to build better sites in the same area

This question asks why SE doesn't help; it *does* help, by providing an easily-parsed (or transformed) data dump and a license that allows anybody at all to take that data and set up another site somewhere else.  The SE software platform isn't available to you, but hostable data is.  It's up to you to host it.

Comment: Thank you for answering and pointing me there, even if I [respectfully disagree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211557/232001) with the reasons given.